# How can I change Menus depending upon domains (url name)?

Tags: 7, routes

I want to change main menu items depending upon domain and sub domains url in a single site.

I could have done it easily with roles, but issue w.r.t anonymous users. How would I show or not certain items in the main menu?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

- Create a main menu per site
- Create a context condition plugin for domain names
- Create a context per domain
- Create a context per site and place the menu block in the navigation region for each context

Profit

If you need to put the same links in multiple menus, check out the [multiple node menu module](https://drupal.org/project/multiple_node_menu).

Comment: I dont know what is that context condition plugin. could be more elaborate.

Comment: I believe that this is the purpose of the [Context Domain module](http://drupal.org/project/context_domain).